# Change Fragment's container height dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I want to change my container's height (which is `PageViewer`) from my fragment class on scroll event of my `ListView`.

**What i have tried already** :-

1.LayoutParams

```
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view1.getLayoutParams();
             params.height = mContainerHeight+ Math.max(a,b);
             view1.requestLayout();
```

Here `view1` is my container.

2.Getting container directly to my fragment class(by FindViewbById) which failed, because my view was in different(parent) layout and we couldn't get views from different layout.

And many more tweaks based on above implementations.

I may be doing this wrong, So i would like tell you what i want to achieve. My container's height should increase to fill the empty space between `Actionbar` and my `ListView`.  when i scroll up container height should increase.

What's happening .[image: Fragment]
Action bar is moving up but Container isnt.

I would really appreciate some help.

**EDIT 1** CODE

AwesomeCardFragment class

```
public class AwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment {

private int mActionBarTitleColor;
private int mActionBarHeight;
private int mHeaderHeight;
private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
private KenBurnsView mHeaderPicture;
private ImageView mHeaderLogo;
private View mHeader;
private View mPlaceHolderView;
private AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator mSmoothInterpolator;

private int mContainerHeight;
private int mMinContainerTranslation;

private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();

private AlphaForegroundColorSpan mAlphaForegroundColorSpan;
private SpannableString mSpannableString;

private TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

// private int position;
ListView mListView;

ViewPager vp;
MainActivity ma;
// Button productButton;
// static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private int position;

// LinearLayout rl;

public static AwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    AwesomeCardFragment f = new AwesomeCardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_slide_main, container, false);

    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    fl.setLayoutParams(params);
    final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());

    mListView = new ListView(getActivity());
    params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    mListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_card);
    // test
    fl.addView(mListView);
    mSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.header_height);
    mMinHeaderTranslation = -mHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight()
            + getActionBarHeight();

    mMinContainerTranslation = mMinHeaderTranslation + getActionBarHeight()
            + getActionBarHeight();
    mHeader = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.header);
    mHeaderPicture = (KenBurnsView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.header_picture);
    mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.picture0, R.drawable.picture1);
    mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.header_logo);

    mActionBarTitleColor = getResources().getColor(
            R.color.actionbar_title_color);

    mSpannableString = new SpannableString(
            getString(R.string.noboringactionbar_title));
    mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(
            mActionBarTitleColor);
    mContainerHeight = container.getHeight();
    setupListView(container);
    return fl;
}

private void setupListView(final ViewGroup view1) {
    ArrayList<String> FAKES = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        FAKES.add("entry " + i);
    }

    mPlaceHolderView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);

    // mPlaceHolderView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().in
    mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FAKES));
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scrollY = getScrollY();
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view1.getLayoutParams();

        Log.i("wtf", "container height"+mContainerHeight);

        params.height = mContainerHeight+ Math.max(-scrollY,
             mMinHeaderTranslation);

             Log.i("wtf", "container height changed"+params.height);

             view1.requestLayout();

             mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY,
                    mMinHeaderTranslation));

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) view1
                    .getLayoutParams();
            if (param != null) {
                param.height = mContainerHeight
                        + Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation);

                view1.setLayoutParams(param);
            }

            // view1.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY,
            // mMinHeaderTranslation));

            // header_logo --> actionbar icon
            float ratio = clamp(mHeader.getTranslationY()
                    / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(),
                    mSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));

            setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));

        }
    });
}
}
```

main xml class which has Container

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height" >

    <com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/header_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/background_tabs" />
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/colors"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/colors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF666666"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FF666666" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF96AA39"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FF96AA39" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFC74B46"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FFC74B46" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF4842D"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FFF4842D" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF3F9FE0"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FF3F9FE0" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF5161BC"
        android:onClick="onColorClicked"
        android:tag="#FF5161BC" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to control your fragment dynamically, then you would have to use `DialogFragment` instead just `Fragment`.

Have a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

You can now include Layout paramters, to control height & width dynamically.

Comment: I want to control my fragment container .

Comment: Then you have write a class which extend that layout so that you can control the View dynamically.